# Add elements on left margin

Tags: pdftex, margins, memoir, tufte

Using `pdflatex`, I am trying to enhance the `memoir` class for my thesis with elements of tufte's layout as done in Aaron Turon's thesis [enter link description here](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~turon/turon-thesis.pdf).

I would like to get the left arrow before synopsis and the section numbering on the left margins as on page 29, see excerpt below.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**

I figured out that the left margin numbering of sections is a built-in feature of memoir, which can be toggled be adding `\setsechook{\hangsecnum}` in the preamble.

How can I add then this beautiful arrow infant of synopsis as shown below?

[image]

Comment: How about posting a small, self-contained example that compiles, instead of a mere picture of what you want?

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. Posting links to external PDF files is of almost no value because many people won't follow them and the links are likely to disappear in the future. Giving a MWE makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will actually try to help!

Comment: Thank you for commenting, guys. I hope you can forgive that I did not provide a MWE, yet, as I am currently AFK. However, I provided a working solution for the first part of my question. How can I solve the other?

Comment: You can use `\sidepar` to put an arrow (►) in the margin.